# How do I get a mean INLCUDING NaN values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Apparently I have the opposite of everyone else's problem... I would like to take the mean of a pandas dataframe, and I would like to have the result return NaN if there are ANY NaNs in the frame. However, it seems like neither np.mean nor np.nanmean do this. Example code:

```
b = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[math.nan,4]])
print(b)
print(np.mean(b))
print(np.nanmean(b))
```

Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: What versions of NumPy and Pandas are you on? I get a Series of columnwise nan-excluding means from `np.mean(b)`.

Comment: @user2357112 I am on numpy 1.26.1 and pandas 2.1.1

Comment: Repeated on 1.26.3 and 2.2.0, in python 3.12.1, got the same results

Comment: @user2357112 That's the exact opposite of what OP is asking. They want the mean to be NaN if there is a NaN present.

Comment: @jared: I know it's not what they're looking for. I'm asking because I'm getting a different result than they got, and I want to check if this is a version difference.

Comment: @user2357112 Understood. I think starting version 2.0 it defaults to returning a scalar rather than column-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using pandas `DataFrame.mean()` function :

```
b.mean(axis=None,skipna=False)
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L3385-L3505) of numpy, the reason that you don't get `nan` from `mean` function is that when numpy sees the input of `mean()` is not multiarray.ndarray, it tries to use `mean` function from that data type if possible.

```
if type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
    try:
        mean = a.mean
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    else:
        return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
```

In your case it is like calling the `mean()` function of `pandas` with `axis=None`. Which is like running the following code:

```
b.mean(axis=None) # 2.333333
```

If you are insisting on using `numpy.mean()` to calculate mean, you can convert your DataFrame to numpy array before callin `np.mean()`.

```
array = b.to_numpy()
np.mean(array) # nan
```

Comment: Note: I think this requires Pandas version 2.0+ in order to return a scalar.